# ¿Cómo hacer una llamada a la API de GPT-3 (openai) usando el modo "Text to command"?

Tags: nodejs, api, test

Sabemos que el modo Text to command que hay disponible en el playgrund de GPT-3 nos permite pasar de una frase u oración en lenguaje natural a un lenguaje formal. Aprovechando esta caracterísitica quiero realizar un generador de test para una API REST genérica. La idea es describir entidades en lenguaje natural, por ejemplo: "un usuario tiene productos" y que el generador de test haga los tests correspondientes a los 4 verbos de la definición de API REST que son:

- POST- Create
- PUT - Update
- DELETE - Remove
- GET - Read

Ahora mismo estoy tratando de generar los tests para el verbo GET únicamente y quiero hacer una llamada a la API, para poder hacerlo de forma automática. Al final de este post pongo el preset que estoy utilizando para definir la tarea, también pongo el JSON que contiene el preset y los parámetros de ajuste de uno de los engines de GPT-3 llamado DaVinci que es el que estoy utilizando.
Partimos de este código:

```
//1. Cargar los datos de entrada (CS3_input.txt) en una variable, cs3_input
//2. Cargar el preset y la configuración Machine Learning contenida en el archivo CS3_Settings.txt, en una variable, cs3_settings
//3. Hacer una llamada a  la API de open AI para obtener el resultado.
//4. Guardar el resultado en una variable de salidad CS3_output.txt

//1. Cargar los datos de entrada (CS3_input.txt) en una variable, cs3_input
// abrir y leer el archivo CS3_input.txt
let fs = require("fs");
let cs3_input = fs.readFileSync("./Backend/controller/CS3_input.txt", "utf8");
//2. Cargar el preset y la configuración Machine Learning contenida en el archivo //CS3_Settings.txt, en una variable, cs3_settings
let cs3_settings = fs.readFileSync("./Presets4GPT3/CS3_Settings.txt", "utf8");
```

La pregunta es sobre el paso 3, el de llamar a la API.
**¿Cómo puedo llamar a la API de open AI para generar un input de respuesta ante un output de pregunta?**

Datos de preset:

```
Q: Create;url:'/admin/clients';data*
A: it('Create clients', done => {
      request(app)
        .post('/admin/clients')
        .send(data)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')
        .set('apikey', global.apikey)
        .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
           DATA_TEST_BLOCK
          done();
        });
    });*
Q: Create;url:'/holidays';data*
A:it('Create holidays', done => {
      request(app)
        .post('/holidays')
        .send(data)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')
        .set('apikey', global.apikey)
        .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
           DATA_TEST_BLOCK
          done();
        });
    });*
Q: Create;url:'/cars';data*

A: it('Create cars', done => {
      request(app)
        .post('/cars')
        .send(data)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')
        .set('apikey', global.apikey)
         .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
           DATA_TEST_BLOCK
          done();
        });
    });*
Q: Create;url:'/boats';data*

A: it('Create boats', done => {
      request(app)
        .post('/boats')
        .send(data)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')
.set('apikey', global.apikey)
         .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .end((err, res) => {
           DATA_TEST_BLOCK
          done();
        });
    });*
Q: Create;url:'/houses';data*
A: it('Create houses', done => {
      request(app)
        .post('/houses')
        .send(data)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
.set('origin', 'LocalHost')
.set('apikey', global.apikey)
.set('token', global.tokenAdmin)
.expect('Content-Type', /json/)
.end((err, res) => {
DATA_TEST_BLOCK
.done();
});
});*
Q: Create;url:'/horses';data*
A: it('Create horses', done => {
      request(app)
        .post('/horses')
        .send(data)
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
.set('origin', 'LocalHost')
.set('apikey', global.apikey)
.set('token', global.tokenAdmin)
.expect('Content-Type', /json/)
.end((err, res) => {
DATA_TEST_BLOCK
.done();
});
});*
```

- Se puede observar que utilizo un '*' para indicar el final de la pregunta y el final de la respuesta.
- Para hacer los test se está usando los módulos de mocha, chai y supertest, así que si no los instalas estos test generados no te valdrán.
- la palabra 'data' tiene que ser sustituida en una etapa posterior por un objeto que depende del esquema de datos utilizado en mongoose (ya que como base de datos estamos usando mongo DB)
- De igual manera la palabra DATA_TEST_BLOCK contiene las sentencias expect(..) que hacen las pruebas particulares y dichas sentencias dependen del modelo de datos definido en mongoose.

JSON con la configuración de Learning Machine:

```
{
  "engine": "davinci",
  "prompt": "Q: Create;url:'/admin/clients';data*\nA: it('Create clients', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/admin/clients')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n        .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/holidays';data*\nA:it('Create holidays', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/holidays')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n        .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/cars';data*\n\nA: it('Create cars', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/cars')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n         .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/boats';data*\n\nA: it('Create boats', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/boats')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n         .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/houses';data*\nA: it('Create houses', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/houses')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n.set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n.set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n.expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n.end((err, res) => {\nDATA_TEST_BLOCK\n.done();\n});\n});*\nQ: Create;url:'/horses';data*\nA: it('Create horses', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/horses')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n.set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n.set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n.expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n.end((err, res) => {\nDATA_TEST_BLOCK\n.done();\n});\n});*\n",
  "temperature": 0.5,
  "max_tokens": 381,
  "top_p": 1,
  "frequency_penalty": 0.2,
  "presence_penalty": 0,
  "stop": ["*"]
}
```

Comment: He visto este link a documentación sobre un paquete de npm para hacer llamadas a la api de openai: https://www.npmjs.com/package/openai-api-node

Comment: La apikey se consigue aquí: https://beta.openai.com/account/api-keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const OpenAI = require("openai-api");
const OPENAI_API_KEY = process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY;
// Carga tu apikey en un servicio de variables de entorno
// (no incluyas tu apikey directamente en el código, especialmente si lo vas a subir //a un repositorio público)

const openai = new OpenAI(OPENAI_API_KEY);
(async () => {
  const gptResponse = await openai.complete({
    engine: "davinci",
    prompt:
      "Q: Create;url:'/admin/clients';data*\nA: it('Create clients', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/admin/clients')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n        .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/holidays';data*\nA:it('Create holidays', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/holidays')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n        .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/cars';data*\n\nA: it('Create cars', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/cars')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n         .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/boats';data*\n\nA: it('Create boats', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/boats')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n         .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/houses';data*\nA: it('Create houses', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/houses')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n.set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n.set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n.expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n.end((err, res) => {\nDATA_TEST_BLOCK\n.done();\n});\n});*\nQ: Create;url:'/horses';data*\nA: it('Create horses', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/horses')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n.set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n.set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n.expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n.end((err, res) => {\nDATA_TEST_BLOCK\n.done();\n});\n});*\nQ: Create;url:'/horses';data*",
    temperature: 0.5,
    max_tokens: 381,
    top_p: 1,
    frequency_penalty: 0.2,
    presence_penalty: 0,
    stop: ["*"],
  });

  console.log(gptResponse.data);
})();
```

- Se ha usado el paquete de npm openai-api (`npm i openai-api`)
- El objeto que va dentro de `openai.complete({ ... })` donde el bloque `{ ... }` es el JSON que puse en el post de mi pregunta.
  Si examinamos el campo prompt de dicho JSON, veremos que contiene el preset:

```
"Q: Create;url:'/admin/clients';data*\nA: it('Create clients', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/admin/clients')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n        .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/holidays';data*\nA:it('Create holidays', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/holidays')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n        .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/cars';data*\n\nA: it('Create cars', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/cars')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n        .set('apikey', global.apikey)\n         .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/boats';data*\n\nA: it('Create boats', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/boats')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n        .set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n         .set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n        .end((err, res) => {\n           DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n          done();\n        });\n    });*\nQ: Create;url:'/houses';data*\nA: it('Create houses', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/houses')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n.set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n.set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n.expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n.end((err, res) => {\nDATA_TEST_BLOCK\n.done();\n});\n});*\nQ: Create;url:'/horses';data*\nA: it('Create horses', done => {\n      request(app)\n        .post('/horses')\n        .send(data)\n        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n.set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n.set('apikey', global.apikey)\n.set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n.expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n.end((err, res) => {\nDATA_TEST_BLOCK\n.done();\n});\n});*\nQ: Create;url:'/horses';data*"
```

y además al final está la pregunta para la que queremos que nos de una respuesta, que en este caso es esta secuencia de carácteres que se encuentra al final del preset:

`Q: Create;url:'/horses';data*`

Si hemos hecho correctamente lo anterior obtendremos una respuesta muy similiar a esta:

```
{
  id: 'cmpl-497yy1TEKD4WcwfgQWi6JocZPb4s5',
  object: 'text_completion',
  created: 1638080984,
  model: 'davinci:2020-05-03',
  choices: [
    {
      text: '\n' +
        "A: it('Create horses', done => {\n" +
        '      request(app)\n' +
        "        .post('/horses')\n" +
        '        .send(data)\n' +
        "        .set('Accept', 'application/json')\n" +
        ".set('origin', 'LocalHost')\n" +
        ".set('apikey', global.apikey)\n" +
        ".set('token', global.tokenAdmin)\n" +
        ".expect('Content-Type', /json/)\n" +
        '.end((err, res) => {\n' +
        'DATA_TEST_BLOCK\n' +
        '.done();\n' +
        '});\n' +
        '});',
      index: 0,
      logprobs: null,
      finish_reason: 'stop'
    }
  ]
}
```